# Detect Month changed in month calendar C#

Tags: c#, winforms

there is a MonthCalender in C#

There is a 2 buttons to select the month

Jan, Feb and so on..

Anyway I can detect that the user changed the month?

Comment: You might be able to add a delegate to the click event of the button but that's a guess, never used that control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
private int MonthValue = 0;
private bool bChanged = false;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MonthValue = monthCalendar1.TodayDate.Month;
}
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{

    if (MonthValue != monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month)
    {
        //changed
        bChanged = true;
        MonthValue = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month;
    }
    else
    {
        //not changed
        bChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea.. that's a correct answer. But that only works when u click the Month's  name and select a different month.

if you click 2 buttons with ">" or "<" icon, it will show the month has changed but it continue changing

Comment: Have you tried using it as for me it works fine using "<" or ">".

Comment: I put a messagebox if it goes into if statement. So the messagebox pops up new month. If i click that new month, next month pops up again.. and it pops up non stop

Comment: Is this what you mean?  private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    
    if (MonthValue != monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month)
    {
        //changed
        bChanged = true;
        MonthValue = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month;
        MessageBox.Show("New month");
    }
    else
    {
        //not changed
        bChanged = false;
        
    }
}

Comment: Yes.. in MessageBox, instead of "New month", I wrote MonthValue.ToString()

So Current month is 10. If I click ">", 11 pops up. When I click OK, 12 pops up followed by 1,2,3 and so on..

Comment: Check your events it might be firing in some other location as well, for me it worked fine.  I only placed the code on the DateChanged event and nothing else.

Comment: yea.. me too.. I created a new proj and drag only one month calender.there are only form load event and date changed event.

Comment: What .Net version are you using? and what OS.  I'm using Win7 and .Net 4, that might have a impact, but not sure

Comment: I found out that the ">" button or the "<" is continue clicking whenever I write something in date changed event. Even a message box showing "Change". keep on showing "Change". My frd is using XP and .net 4, also have the same problem.

Comment: IT IS WORKING.. as long as you don't pop up any message box.

Answer (score 0):

use `OnVisibleMonthChanged` on calender control and create event something like this:

```
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Further processing goes here
        }
```